# Автоматическая оптимизация под конкретную платформу

Tags: оптимизация, компиляция

Существует ли ПО, позволяющее автоматически настраивать компилятор для оптимизации именно под тот ПК, на котором производится компиляция?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду автоматический подбор `-march=` в gcc? Так он там и так есть вроде. Автоматически подбирать остальные параметры оптимизации я бы машине не доверил.

Comment: @VladD, да, `-march=`. Но где-то читал про ПО, якобы тестирующее при оптимизации отдельные участки программы.

Comment: Вы наверное имеете в виду [PGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization)? Вопрос в том, что мы собираемся оптимизировать: скорость работы одного участка кода может означать замедление другого. Например, если заинлайнить все функции, мы выиграем расходы на вызов, но потеряем cache locality. Так что с оптимизацией не так всё просто.

Comment: @VladD, да-да, PGO. Уже нашёл интересующий [материал](https://habrahabr.ru/post/138132/).